# How to make a dynamic table in a web page in django?

Tags: html, django, dynamic

I'm using Django to build my app I need to retrieve data from database and put it in a dynamic table in html page.
Help please.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question. What, exactly, are you having trouble with?

Comment: i have for example 2 parameter in my database name and lastname i need to put it in dynamic table in HTML page for each row in my database i can display alls rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/)!

```
<table>
    {% for key, value in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ key|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```